# Showing a particular set is Borel

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Let $f:X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, here $X$ and $Y$ are connected and simply connected separable metric spaces.  Let $U\subseteq Y$ be non-empty and open.  I want to show that the set
$$
Z = \left\{
x \in X: \, (\exists y \in U)\, f(x,y) \geq 0
\right\},
$$
is Borel measurable but I'm totally stumped.  I've tried to represent this as
$$
Z = \bigcup_{y \in U} f^{-1}(\cdot,y)[[0,\infty)],
$$
but the uncountable union of closed sets needs not be closed.... So I'm abit stumped.

I feel that since $U$ is open, and not closed, we can reduce the argument to a countable dense subset of $U$ (since the separability of $Y$), but I'm not sure how...

Comment: $Z$ needs not be Borel, I think, but it is Lebesgue measurable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P=f^{-1}[[0,\infty)]$ which is closed in $X \times Y$. Then $Z= \pi_X[P \cap (X \times U)]$ is an [analytic set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) and as such [Lebesgue measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_measurable_set). I think it's safer to assume $X,Y$ are Polish spaces, instead of (irrelevant) connectedness assumptions.

Comment: @Zorn'sLama Yes, that ensures that $Z$ is analytic.

Comment: In general, are there conditions on the spaces/ on f (non-trivial) assuring that it would be Borel and not only Lebesgue?

Comment: @Zorn'sLama so e,g. if $X,Y$ are $\sigma$-compact, so is $X \times Y$ and $X \times U$ and $(X \times U) \cap P$, and hence the image under $\pi_Y$ too is $F_\sigma$. So for $X=Y=\Bbb R$ we have Borel sets.

Comment: Do you have a reference to this latter remark?  Alternatively, I could try to make due with using a completion of $B(X)$ wrt some Borel probability measure but then I'm uncertain if the resulting measure is Radon (which I have to investigate).

Comment: @Zorn'sLama It's obvious and needs no reference. I use that open sets are $F_\sigma$'s in metric spaces and $F_\sigma$'s in  $\sigma$-compact spaces are $\sigma$-compact, all easily proved.